# Implicit method for typeclass not found

Tags: scala, typeclass, shapeless

This is continuation of [Diverging implicit expansion for type class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33787931/371804). I've came up with another version that still doesn't compile, but now for another reason, hence a different question. Here's what I did:

I've basically added a new typeclass `NestedParser` for the cases where some case class consists of other case classes.

```
trait Parser[A] {
  def apply(s: String): Option[A]
}
trait NestedParser[A] {
  def apply(s: String): Option[A]
}

object Parser {
  def apply[A](s: String)(implicit parser: Parser[A]): Option[A] = parser(s)
}
object NestedParser {
  def apply[A](s: String)(implicit parser: NestedParser[A]): Option[A] = parser(s)
}
```

I've changed the previous implicit function to return the `NestedParser` to avoid diverging implicit expansions. Otherwise it's same as before:

```
implicit def nestedCaseClassParser[A, B, C]
  (
    implicit pb: Parser[B],
    pc: Parser[C],
    gen: Generic.Aux[A, B :: C :: HNil]
  ): NestedParser[A] = new NestedParser[A] {
    override def apply(s: String): Option[A] = {
      val tmp = s.span(_ != '|') match {
        case (h, t) =>
          for {
            a <- pb(h)
            b <- pc(t.substring(1))
          } yield a :: b :: HNil
      }
      tmp.map(gen.from)
    }
  }
```

Case classes are same as before:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
case class Family(husband: Person, wife: Person)
```

Now when I try to parse the `Family`, I get the following compile error:

```
scala> NestedParser[Family]("")
<console>:32: error: could not find implicit value for parameter parser: NestedParser[Family]
       NestedParser[Family]("")
```

However, it doesn't make sense to me. The function above clearly provides the implicit instance of `NestedParser`. Why doesn't it satisfy the compiler?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I can see you are not providing any implicit `Parser` instances which `nestedCaseClassParser` requires.

Comment: Since it's continuation of another question, I haven't posted the complete code. In fact, the code is taken from this blog post: https://meta.plasm.us/posts/2015/11/08/type-classes-and-generic-derivation/. I've only added `NestedParser` trait and companion object and the `implicit def nestedCaseClassParser[A, B, C]`